# How to add Fontawesome to an Input Type Button

Tags: button, input, types

```
<td class="jit_rep_jit_seq" nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align: center; visibility: visible;" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><input class="active_c_ax" id="LOC_ID43258" onclick='DoMoveAxlStack("43258","4");' type="button" value="CRBAY-4"></td>
  <input class="active_c_ax" id="LOC_ID43258" onclick='DoMoveAxlStack("43258","4");' type="button" value="CRBAY-4">
</td>
```

This is the imput that resides with a table  data cell it is of type button.I would like to add a Fontawesome image to the button. However I am not sure how to do this. Please can you advise?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

**CSS**

```
input[type="button"] {
font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I added that to my page css but I did not see anything what else do I have to do I would like to add  fa fa-cog to this type=button